# Using map instead of a for loop by iterating over list length and using list values

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my program I have 6 different models and 6 indexes for each of them. I want to count the index frequency by looping over an `index`  tensor to see which one of my models is getting ahead.

`index`  tensor is here frequency of indexes for each run and contains 4096 values between 0-5.

My current code looks like:

```
freq = [0]*6
for idx in index:
    freq[idx] += 1
```

But that takes so long(single call takes 0.3s and I call this loop 500.000 times) and makes the code very slow. So I decided to speed this loop with a map function and wrote this instead:

```
freq = [0]*6
freq = list(map(lambda x: freq[x] + 1 , index))
```

But it doesn't work as its supposed to. `freq` just adds 1 for each element of `index`  and at the end it gives a list full of 1's with a length of 4096.

A proper output would look like:

```
[433, 732, 271, 1628, 711, 321]
```

which adds up to 4096.

An example for `index`

```
tensor([4, 3, 1,  ..., 4, 5, 1], device='cuda:0')
```

which has 4096 elements. How could I fix that map function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `map` gives a new list and you are updating the list for each `batch`. You are missing that second level loop and you can't do that with `map` because the value read from `freq` will always be 0

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, make sure all variables are defined. In your first example, `batch` is undefined and in the second example `index` is undefined. It will help if you can show a simplified example of the input data as well.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I simply want to increase the releated freq value by 1 for each input. Wouldn't that be possible with map?

Comment: im not sure what the issue is here, you start with a list of 0s and `+1` and get a list of 1s, isn't that the expected output?

Comment: @ksooklall I am counting the frequency of 6 models. index is a tensor for 4096 runs. In each run one model gets better results. I save the model index, which had good results into index tensor. So now I have the good model for each run. But I need to count the frequency of them and want to save the frequency into a list named freq, which has 6 elements(repeat frequency of each model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (assuming `x` is your input vector):

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
x=np.random.randint(1,7, size=4096)

y=Counter(x)
res=np.array(sorted(y.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))[:, 1]
```

Output (it's uniform distribution):

```py
[722 639 665 683 697 690]
```